# Transparency on GLB model and Three.js viewer

Tags: three.js, 3d, gltf

I am trying to create and display a model with per-vertix color and transparency.

Demo app here: https://diego3d.azurewebsites.net/repl (click on Run and wait 10 to 15 seconds).

Using SharpGLTF to generate the model as follows:

```
                    for (int i = 0; i < mesh.IndexCount / 3; i++)
                {
                    var v0 = mesh.Vertices[mesh.Indices[3 * i + 0]];
                    var v1 = mesh.Vertices[mesh.Indices[3 * i + 1]];
                    var v2 = mesh.Vertices[mesh.Indices[3 * i + 2]];

                    var VERTEX0 = new VERTEXPOSITIONNORMAL((float)v0.Position.X, (float)v0.Position.Y, (float)v0.Position.Z, (float)v0.Normal.X, (float)v0.Normal.Y, (float)v0.Normal.Z);
                    var VERTEX1 = new VERTEXPOSITIONNORMAL((float)v1.Position.X, (float)v1.Position.Y, (float)v1.Position.Z, (float)v1.Normal.X, (float)v1.Normal.Y, (float)v1.Normal.Z);
                    var VERTEX2 = new VERTEXPOSITIONNORMAL((float)v2.Position.X, (float)v2.Position.Y, (float)v2.Position.Z, (float)v2.Normal.X, (float)v2.Normal.Y, (float)v2.Normal.Z);

                    var c0 = new VERTEXCOLOR(new Vector4(v0.Color.R / 255f, v0.Color.G / 255f, v0.Color.B / 255f, v0.Color.A / 255f));
                    var c1 = new VERTEXCOLOR(new Vector4(v1.Color.R / 255f, v1.Color.G / 255f, v1.Color.B / 255f, v1.Color.A / 255f));
                    var c2 = new VERTEXCOLOR(new Vector4(v2.Color.R / 255f, v2.Color.G / 255f, v2.Color.B / 255f, v2.Color.A / 255f));

                    glbPrim.AddTriangle((VERTEX0, c0), (VERTEX1, c1), (VERTEX2, c2));
                }
```

Using Three.js GLTFLoader to display the model as follows:

```
    new RGBELoader()
    .setDataType(THREE.UnsignedByteType)
    .setPath('../js/ThreeJs/models/textures/equirectangular/')
    .load('studio_small_04_1k.hdr', function (texture) {

        const envMap = pmremGenerator.fromEquirectangular(texture).texture;

        scene.background = envMap;
        scene.environment = envMap;

        texture.dispose();
        pmremGenerator.dispose();

        render();

        const loader = new GLTFLoader().setPath('../api/').setRequestHeader({ codeText: '' });
        loader.parse(data, '../api/', function (gltf) {
            var object = gltf.scene;
            object.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);
            scene.remove(scene.getObjectByName("glbModel"));
            object.name = 'glbModel';
            lastModel = object;
            scene.add(object);
            render();
        });
        console.log(data.length)
    });
```

The model displays as created but no transparency. I'm new to GLTF and Three.js, any pointers on this? Thanks.

Comment: The material in this glTF file is marked with `alphaMode="OPAQUE"` — for vertex alpha to have any effect, you'll need to replace that with `alphaMode="BLEND"` or `alphaMode="MASK"`.

Comment: I am using the following setup in SharpGLTF right before the vertex creation shown above.

var material1 = new MaterialBuilder()
                .WithDoubleSide(true)
                .WithAlpha(AlphaMode.MASK)
                ;

            var glbMesh = new MeshBuilder<VERTEXPOSITIONNORMAL, VERTEXCOLOR, VertexEmpty>("mesh");
            var glbPrim = glbMesh.UsePrimitive(material1);
 The key line is .WithAlpha(AlphaMode.MASK)

Comment: Sorry, not sure why the format gets messed up.

I included .WithAlpha(AlphaMode.MASK) in the model creation.

Comment: And, just for clarity, I am not talking about the cube that is displayed initially but about the model that gets downloaded once the code is run. Correct?

Comment: I'm checking the GLB in the demo, https://diego3d.azurewebsites.net/js/ThreeJs/models/BoxVertexColors.glb. It's definitely got alphaMode="OPAQUE" set on its only material... if I manually change that the transparency appears. You can check the alpha mode with `gltf-transform inspect model.glb` (https://gltf-transform.donmccurdy.com/cli.html).

Comment: Got it, thanks. That file is just used on startup. When you click RUN a new model is generated on the server and loaded on the client. It shows up fine but without transparency.

I'll set a test file there as well and check it per your suggestion.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy, thanks for your help.
Haven't found it but I think my issue is on the SharpGLTF generation.
I'm working on other areas for now, will come back to transparency soon.